# Update Backbone.js model in MySQL database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, backbone.js

I have the following model:

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/save.php",
    defaults: {
        color: "red"
    }
});
```

When the document is ready I create a new instance of the model and save it:

```
new volvo = new Car({color:"green"});
volvo.save();
```

Then in the server I assign the new car an id and return it to the client (whith PHP):

```
$request_method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

switch ($request_method) {
    case 'post':
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        $color = $data->{'color'};
        $car = array('id'=>1, 'color'=>$color);
        echo json_encode($car); //I use this to send the response to the client
                               //but I am not sure if this is the right way
    break;

    case 'put':
        //code to handle this case
    break;
}
```

The problem is that when I want to update the new instance of the car model, volvo, backbone assumes that volvo is always a new model and therefore a request with POST is made, but I want it to update the existing model, volvo, like this:

```
new volvo = new Car({color:"green"});
volvo.save();

console.log( volvo.attributes ); //in here an id appears
console.log( volvo.get('id') ); //this returns 'undefined' 

volvo.save({color:"red"}); //this saves in the database a new model, not desired
```

Any ideas on why is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check this example:

```
var volvo = new Car({color:"green"});

// Create a new car model.
console.log(volvo.isNew());  // Output: true
volvo.save();

console.log(volvo.isNew());  // Output: false
console.log(volvo.id);   // Output: 1
// Update the color of the already created model to red.
volvo.save({color:"red"});
```

Now if you want to get the already created model in another part of your code you will have to know the id.

```
var volvo = new Car({id: 1});

// Update the model.
console.log(volvo.isNew());  // Output: false
volvo.save({color: "blue"});
```

Remarque: The server should return the **JSON** of the model created with the id.

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: I tried this, but the result is not like in the comments. Each time .isNew() returns true and volvo.id is undefined. In this way two POST request are send, so I get two models: "green" and "red", both with id:1

Comment: Can you please give me a hint on how can I return the JSON from the server, I am doing it with 'echo', but I am not sure if this does it. I can see a HTTP response with Firebug, but I do not know if this is how it should be done.

Comment: @rpabon: I'm not good with PHP but given the example from here https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-cellar/blob/master/tutorial/api/index.php i see that you're doing it correctly ! Sorry i couldn't help

Comment: @rpabon: You can use firebug to check the response of the server (Check the **Net** tab)

Answer (score 1):

Check that you really send the id attribute in the post response. Models without id's are considered as new, so are created instead of updated when saving.